# CSS Errors in loading safari pages

Tags: css, safari, safari-web-inspector

I updated to OS El Capitan 10.11.2 and it has interfered with my Safari experience (I think). I am somehow not able to see any pages in my Google Drive (Docs, Slides, Sheets), but I can use every other site perfectly fine.

When I open the error console in Safari it states the below, then Safari reloads saying: "A problem occurred with this web page so it was reloaded." It will do this for forever until the tab is closed.

```
Viewport argument key "minimum-scale:1.0" not recognized and ignored.
Viewport argument key "maximum-scale:1.0" not recognized and ignored.
Unexpected CSS token: :
**DOES THIS ONE ^ FOR ABOUT 5 TIMES**
Invalid CSS property declaration at: *
**DOES THIS ONE^ FOR ABOUT 10 TIMES**
```

At the moment the sites: Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Drawings don't work. And I am sure this problem is isolated to my machine since I can access those sites on other computers.

Also I have tried booting up in safe mode but I still can't access the sites.

Additional INFO:

OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Safari Ver: 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)

Macbook Pro (mid 2009)